# Every open subset of a locally connected space is locally connected

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove :

> Every open subset $U$ of a locally connected space $X$ is locally
>   connected.

There is already a topic ([Show that every open subset of a locally connected space is locally connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402007/show-that-every-open-subset-of-a-locally-connected-space-is-locally-connected?rq=1)) that deals with this question, but for some reason, I can't understand what they are actually saying there (maybe because we have different definitions of "local connectedness").

> To me, a space $X$ is locally connected means : every point of $X$ has
>   a connected neighborhood.

Here is my try. Let $x \in U$. Since $X$ is locally connected, there exists $C$ connected subspace of $X$ and $V$ open in $X$ such that $x \in V \subset C$. So $x \in U \cap V \subset U \cap C \subset U$, where $U \cap V$ is an open set of $U$, but the problem is that I can't say $U \cap C$ is connected, as there are cases where the intersection of a connected set and an open set has infinitely many connected components.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit :**

Sorry, the actual definition of "local connectedness" is :

> A space $X$ is locally connected if every point $x \in X$ has a neighborhood base consisting of connected subspaces.

Here is the proof of the aforementioned result.

Let $V$ an open subset of $U$ such that $x \in V \subset U$. Since $U$ is open in $X$, $V$ is open in $X$. Since $X$ is locally connected, there exists $x\in W \subset C \subset V$ where $W$ is open in $X$ and $C$ is connected. Note that $W$ is then open in $V$. So $C$ does the job.

Comment: If there are many connected components, why don't you just take the connected component containing $x$?

Comment: That is *not* the definition of *locally connected*; it isn’t even weak local connectedness.

Comment: @AlexM. : That doesn't work either.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : Thanks. I wrote the solution.

Comment: The def in my text states :A topological space X is locally connected if the components of each open subset of X are open